# is there a way to use collapsible checkboxes with categories in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have this big List of Values that can be quite hard to get through all of it when you only need to check a couple  of boxes. So is there a way to group the boxes in categories?

This is my list of values:

```
select name_objectif, id_objectif
from Objectif
```

Where every objectif belongs to some category.

A way to filter the checkboxes can also be helpful.

Comment: So where do the categories come from? Is there a category ID on `objectif`?

Comment: yes, it can. the way i'm doing it is categories have many objectifs

Comment: You need to **edit your question** to explain that relationship and you you want to use it to restrict the LOV

Comment: the apex tag does not apply to Oracle APEX. It relates to the Force.com product.